# Prove $BG || EC$ by pure geometric method.

Tags: geometry, plane-geometry

> Let $E$ be a point outside square $ABCD$ such that $AE=AC$, $F$ be a
>   point on $AE$ such that $DE=DF$, and $G$ be the intersection point of
>   $AC,BF$ and satisfy $BG=EC$.Prove that $BG||EC$.

[image]

This conclusion is easy to verify by constructing figure. And, we can see $\angle EAC=30^o$. But how to prove it by **pure geometric method** only? THX in advance.

Comment: Something looks strange to me : as line BG is identical to line BF, your issue could be said in this way : proof that BF// CE... therefore **no need to introduce point $G$**. I think that there is somethin hidden there : in fact the property could be richer : prove that $\vec{BG}=\vec{CE}$. Isn't it that ?

Answer (score 0):

*This is probably not a 'pure' geometrical proof but may be of some interest.*

As you have pointed out the configuration, **C** say, with $\angle BAG=45^o$, $\angle ABG=30^o$ is easy to find so all that is necessary is to prove there are no other solutions.

Let $AD$ have unit length and, initially, ignore the condition $BG=EC$. Then the locus of $E$ is a circle centre $A$.

As $E$ moves anti-clockwise from $C$ until it reaches the line $AD$, the mid-point of $E$ and $F$ moves on a circle with $AD$ as diameter and so $F$ moves on a limacon (the relevant part of which is part of a simple convex loop with $AD$ as a line of symmetry) from $A$ until it reaches the line $AD$ again (at distance $(2-\sqrt 2)$ from $A$).

During this 'motion', $|CE|$ increases from $0$ while $|BG|$ decreases from $1$. These lengths become equal at position **C**. In this configuration $BG$ intersects the limacon at $15^o$ to its tangent and intersects $AD$ inside the limacon. Therefore there is only one position where $BG=CE$.